# Using SDWebImage to iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage for my app.

I downloaded ASWebImage files from this
[link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Added into myapp. Then i Imported UIImageView+WebCache.h

When i run my app i am getting exception.

here is my code

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)]
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/a.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

When i run this app i am getting following exception.

```
[UIImageView setImageWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e64390
2012-08-23 19:32:14.828 test123[16941:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e64390'
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have imported "ImageIO.framework"

Answer (score 2):

In order to resolve this issue, please refer to the project installation instructions. I had the same error, however as soon as I followed the installation instructions, the issue was resolved immediately.

You can find those instructions here: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#installation

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the SDWebImage library with your app? How about the linker flag -ObjC?

Comment: No. I didn't linked. could u please tell me how to add a linker flag?

Comment: Find the "Build Phases" section in your project settings, and then look for the Link Binary with Libraries section to make sure you've added the library into the build. Then check the "Build Settings" tab and add `-ObjC` to the Other Linker Flags field.

Comment: Basically, make sure you followed all the steps in the installation section of the README - https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#installation